Sprockets::FileNotFound - couldn't find file 'active_admin/base' with type 'text/css' Rails 6
I have been facing this issue from past couple of days once I upgraded to Rails 6.1
Have looked around possible solutions but no success
Error
Sprockets::FileNotFound - couldn't find file 'active_admin/base' with type 'text/css'
Checked in these paths: 

Gemfile
gem "sprockets-rails", :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
gem 'sprockets'

Gemfile.lock
sprockets (4.2.1)
 concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (>= 2.2.4, < 4)
    sprockets-rails (3.5.2)
      actionpack (>= 6.1)
      activesupport (>= 6.1)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)

tailwind-active_admin.config.js
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
const activeAdminPath = execSync('bundle show activeadmin', { encoding: 'utf-8' }).trim();

module.exports = {
  content: [
    `${activeAdminPath}/vendor/javascript/flowbite.js`,
    `${activeAdminPath}/plugin.js`,
    `${activeAdminPath}/app/views/**/*.{arb,erb,html,rb}`,
    './app/admin/**/*.{arb,erb,html,rb}',
    './app/views/active_admin/**/*.{arb,erb,html,rb}',
    './app/views/admin/**/*.{arb,erb,html,rb}',
    './app/views/layouts/active_admin*.{erb,html}',
    './app/javascript/**/*.js'
  ],
  darkMode: "selector",
}

webpack.config.js
const path    = require("path")
const webpack = require("webpack")

module.exports = {
  mode: "production",
  devtool: "source-map",
  entry: {
    application: "./app/javascript/application.js"
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    sourceMapFilename: "[file].map",
    chunkFormat: "module",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "app/assets/builds"),
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.LimitChunkCountPlugin({
      maxChunks: 1
    })
  ]
}

package.json
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": "true",
  "dependencies": {
    "@activeadmin/activeadmin": "3.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.6.0",
    "arctic_admin": "^4.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.10"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build:css": "tailwindcss -i ./app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css -o ./app/assets/builds/active_admin.css --minify -c tailwind-active_admin.config.js"
  },
  "packageManager": "yarn@1.22.22"
}

/app/assets/stylesheets/active_admin.css
/* 
*= require font-awesome
*= require active_admin/base
*= require active_admin/mixins
*= require select2
*= require_tree .
*/

/app/assets/javascripts/active_admin.js
//= require active_admin/base

/app/assets/config/manifest.js
//= link_tree ../images
//= link_directory ../javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../../../vendor/assets/javascripts .js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .css
//= link_directory ../stylesheets .scss
//= link_tree ../builds

Rails 6.1.7.10
Ruby 3.2.2

Not an expert in frontend technology but from my understanding you should be using webpack or sprockets not both
